# WHERE clause using OPENQUERY with linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I connect with *MS SQL Server Express 2012* a Database via ODBC.

My query:

```
Select * from openquery(test,'SELECT * FROM Versuchsanlage_DB WHERE value =27')
```

[image: SQL QUERY]

But this query

```
 Select * from openquery(test,
   'SELECT * FROM Versuchsanlage_DB 
    WHERE identifier = AGENT.OBJECTS.Versuchsanlage.Variable_1_Byte')
```

OR

```
Select * from openquery(test,
   'SELECT * FROM Versuchsanlage_DB
    WHERE identifier = Variable_1_Byte')
```

doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're searching for a string value in the `identifier` column. Strings must be enclosed in quotes. Since the select statement is being passed to `OPENQUERY` as a string, quotes inside that string must be escaped:

```
Select * from openquery(test,
   'SELECT * FROM Versuchsanlage_DB 
    WHERE identifier = ''AGENT.OBJECTS.Versuchsanlage.Variable_1_Byte''')
```

OR

```
Select * from openquery(test,
       "SELECT * FROM Versuchsanlage_DB 
        WHERE identifier = 'AGENT.OBJECTS.Versuchsanlage.Variable_1_Byte'")
```

These queries are functionally the same, one just uses all single-quotes while the other uses double-quotes. Pick whichever you think is easier to read.

Alternatively you could drop `OPENQUERY` and use `EXECUTE...AT` syntax for parameterization (this requires RPC to be enabled for the linked server):

```
EXECUTE('SELECT * FROM Versuchsanlage_DB WHERE identifier = ?',
        'AGENT.OBJECTS.Versuchsanlage.Variable_1_Byte') AT [test];
```